# Find $\theta$ in the following diagram

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

$ABCD$ is a square.  The angles are given as shown.  Find angle $\theta$.

**My attempt:**

Applying the law of sines in $\triangle ABP $:

$ \dfrac{ r }{ \sin 70^\circ } = \dfrac{ a }{\sin(70^\circ + \theta) } $

where $a$ is the side length of the square.

Applying the law of sines in $\triangle BCP $:

$ \dfrac{ r } { \sin 65^\circ} = \dfrac{ a }{ \sin( 65^\circ + 90^\circ - 
\theta ) } $

Dividing these equation

$ \dfrac{ \sin 65^\circ}{\sin 70^\circ} = \dfrac{ \sin(155^\circ - \theta)}{\sin(70^\circ + \theta) } $

Cross multiplying

$ \sin 65^\circ \sin(70^\circ + \theta) = \sin 70^\circ \sin(155^\circ - \theta) $

Expanding,

$ \sin 65^\circ ( \sin 70^\circ \cos \theta + \cos 70^\circ \sin \theta ) = \sin 70^\circ (\sin 155^\circ \cos \theta - \cos 155^\circ \sin \theta )$

Divding through by $\cos \theta$

$ \sin 65^\circ ( \sin 70^\circ + \cos 70^\circ \tan \theta ) = \sin 70^\circ ( \sin 155^\circ - \cos 155^\circ \tan \theta ) $

From which,

$ \tan \theta = \dfrac{ \sin 70^\circ ( \sin 155^\circ - \sin 65^\circ) }{ \sin 65^\circ \cos 70^\circ + \sin 70^\circ \cos 155^\circ} $

Calculating the above,

$\tan \theta = 0.83909963118 $

Hence,

$ \theta = \tan^{-1}(0.83909963118) = 40^\circ $

I would like to verify this answer.

Your comments, hints, or alternative solutions are highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First Solution:**

[image]

By rotating $\triangle APB$ anticlockwise rotation  $90^{\circ}$ through vertex $B$ that is $\triangle ECB$

Since $\angle PBE = 90^{\circ}, BP=BE$ then $\angle BPE = \angle BEP = 45^{\circ}$ (isosceles right $\triangle$)

$\angle PCE =65^{\circ} + 70^{\circ}=135^{\circ}$

Since $\angle PBE + 2\times \angle PCE = 90^{\circ} + 2\times 135^{\circ} = 360^{\circ}$ then there is a circle centred at $B$ through the points $P,C$ and $E$.

Then $\angle CPE = \frac{\theta}{2}$ ($\angle$ at centre $=2\times \angle$ at circumference)

$90^{\circ} - \theta + 45^{\circ} + \frac{\theta}{2} + 65^{\circ} = 180^{\circ}$ (sum of $\angle$'s in $\triangle$)

$\theta = 40^{\circ}$

**Second Solution:**
[image]

$\angle APB=135^{\circ}$ and $\angle B + 2\times \angle APB= 90^{\circ} + 2\times 135^{\circ} = 360^{\circ}$ then there is a circle centred at $B$ through the points $A,P$ and $C$.

Draw diagonal $AC$

$\angle PCA = \frac{\angle ABP}{2} = \frac{\theta}{2}$ ($\angle$ at centre $=2\times \angle$ at circumference)

$\frac{\theta}{2} = 65^{\circ} - 45^{\circ} =20^{\circ}$

$\theta = 40^{\circ}$

**Third Solution:**

$\angle APB=135^{\circ}$ and $\angle B + 2\times \angle APB= 90^{\circ} + 2\times 135^{\circ} = 360^{\circ}$ then there is a circle centred at $B$ through the points $A,P$ and $C$.

then $BA=BP$,(radius) and $\angle BAP=\angle BPA=70^{\circ}$

then $\theta=40^{\circ}$

Comment: Note on the second approach. Once you know that $A$, $P$ and $C$ lie on a circle centered in $B$, then the result is obtained by observing that $APB$ is isosceles.

Comment: @dfnu : Thanks, I added this solution

Answer (score 0):

I will give an alternate approach, Draw lines perpendicular to PB from A and C, cutting PB at points E and F.

Consider triangle APB, where $r=PE+BE$, $BE = acos\theta$ and $PE = atan(20°+ \theta)sin\theta$. $r = acos\theta +  atan(20°+ \theta)sin\theta$.
Similarly, you can find an equation with triangle CPB. By dividing the equations, you can solve for theta to get the answer.

Thank you